# Open angular material Snackbar in service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to show the user Errors through a Snackbar. Which is totally fine when I open a Snackbar through a component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.snackBar.open('message');
    }
}
```

But when I want to open a Snackbar in my DataService it throws this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
```

My DataService looks like this:

```
export class DataService {

  private api = 'https://localhost:5001/api/';

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
  }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get(this.api, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        retry(3), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
        catchError(this.handleError) // then handle the error
      );
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }

    this.snackBar.open('Something bad happened, please try again later.');

    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }
}
```

So, after the third attempt of getting Data it goes into the handleError() and should open a SnackBar with "Something bad happened, please try again later."

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to open in your ngOnInit function in the component?

Comment: This was only an example for showing that in a component it is possible to open a Snackbar.

Comment: Hello tidi00, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you check if you have imported `MatSnackBar` into that file and have imported `MatSnackBarModule` into your main app's module?

Comment: Hello Edric, yes I have imported MatSnackBar into data.service.ts and MatSnackBarModule into the app.module.ts.

Comment: Did you import the service in your app's module file?

Comment: No I didn't! Where in the NgModule should I import the service (declarations, imports, ...)?

Comment: The service should be imported into the `providers` array and have the `Injectable` decorator on top of the class export. (See https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services for more info.)

Comment: I read the documentation on https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services and provided the service in the whole app with `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`. But it still can't open a snack bar!

Comment: same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, apparently it is ok when the `handleError()` method gets triggered from a component.                                                                                               `private getData(): void {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
      (Data: Data) => this.Data = Data,
      error => this.dataService.handleError(error)
    );
  }`

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the current scope inside `catchError` is not the class itself and thus

```
this.snackbar
```

is not defined. To fix this, there are 2 methods

**Method 1:**

You can return your callback function from inside another function to preserve the scope as

```
private handleError() {
    return (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        //your logic
    }
}
```

and change your `catchError` method as

```
catchError(this.handleError())  //note the parenthesis on handleError
```

**Method 2:**

Simply bind the callback method in `catchError` to `this` as

```
this.ErrorHandler.bind(this)
```